# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError for method on the build path

Tags: android

I have a basic Android project created in Eclipse Indigo. I have a third-party library on my build path, and it is called is used when I instantiate a class from that library in my initial activity.

Although the app build just fine, I encounter the following error:
`10-02 19:51:17.311: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>`

Earlier in logcat, I do observe the following error message:
`10-02 19:50:48.670: DEBUG/dalvikvm(295): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/Scheme;': multiple definitions`

This class is included in the third-party JAR; is it used by Android somehow/somewhere to suggest a conflict or other source of "multiple definitions?"

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like that is already available in Android SDK. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/scheme/package-summary.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Jack. How does one reconcile the conflict - do I have crack open the third-party JAR and exclude the conflicting files?

Comment: That is the million dollar question. Have you checked your imports to make sure you are NOT using the one included in Android? Also - what is this third party jar you are using? Maybe someone else has experienced this and knows the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does one reconcile the conflict - do I have crack open the third-party JAR and exclude the conflicting files?

My guess is that this would not help, though you can certainly try it. Somebody would appear to be trying to call a method on `Scheme` that perhaps exists in the JAR's own private copy of that class but is not in the Android SDK.

If the third-party JAR in question is Apache HttpClient, simply don't put that JAR in your build path, as HttpClient is already part of Android, and stick to methods that are in the SDK. If the third-party JAR is *not* Apache HttpClient, I suspect that once you remove their duplicate `org.apache.http` classes, that something else will break that depended on their own private version of those classes. If that is the case, you should probably take it up with the third-party developer directly, to work with them on Android support for their JAR. You *might* be able to use tools like `jarjar` to get past this, but I would not count on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like [jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/),  it can break open the jars and rename the packages to a different path at build time. This avoids conflicts like the ones you're having. I'm just not sure it will work with Android.